# Entity Framework не могу установить процедуру в источник сущности

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Возникла проблема с создаем связей в EF. У нас бизнес-логика лежит в процедурах на сервере, в плоть до отдельных процедур на выборку/удаление/добавление/изменение (не весь функционал но есть такие моменты).

По умолчанию EF создает сложный тип для получения данных из процедур. Но мне нужна именно сущность.

Пытаюсь создать главную сущность (entity) и сделать связку с дочерней чтобы можно было смотреть детализацию в master-detail grid. Но EF не дает связать сущность с процедурой, прочитал  что ему нужно либо представление либо таблица для сущности. Переписать естественно нельзя так как это исторически сложилось.

Можно ли обмануть EF чтобы он принял процедуру а не таблицу для сущности?

Comment: [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/async-and-stored-procedures-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), [2](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/CRUD-using-stored-procedures.aspx). Почти в каждом туториале по EF рассказывают, как работать с хранимками.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это не та ситуация которую описывают в туториалах

Comment: Я не вижу никакой разницы. Есть хранимки. Создаём сущность, связываем её с ними. Всё.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov В том то и дело что нет, нельзя связать сущность с процедурой, иначе я бы не писал сюда.

Comment: Ну как нельзя, если именно это и описано в туториалах? Но, кажется, я понял, в чём у вас проблема: ваши хранимки возвращают данные не из одной таблицы, а объединённые данные из нескольких таблиц. Так? А вам хотелось бы эти объединённые данные поместить не в один сложный тип, не имеющий прямого отображения на таблицу, а в несколько.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov почти но не совсем, Вы правильно сказали что я получаю данные из нескольких таблиц, притом еще с параметрами и другими сложными там преобразованиями, но я хочу поместить это объединение в одну сущность (а не сложный тип), так как потом к этой сущности идут связи с другими сущностями один ко многим, дочерние сущности так же грузятся с помощью процедур по ключу.

Comment: Тогда просто откажитесь от EF. Он вам не нужен. ORM предназначена как раз для того, чтобы не писать вручную запросы. А они у вас уже написаны в хранимках.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А как тогда данные по вашему я буду получать? А потом еще их обновлять? Мы уже писали руками запросы через стандартный SqlDataAdapter. Нет уж спасибо, написались.

Comment: То есть вы решили отказаться от хранимок? Хорошо.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov нет мы и тогда не отказывались от хранимок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ли обмануть EF чтобы он принял процедуру а не таблицу для
>   сущности?

В подавляющем большинстве случаев, в БД сущность это так или иначе таблица или представление. Бывают исключения, но как правило вследствие кривизны архитектуры.

Поэтому и EF воспринимает сущности только так и никак иначе.

Если исправить положение не поломав работу действующего софта никак нельзя, можно попробовать воспользоваться паттерном "Репозиторий" и вытащить объект сущности через объект репозитория, который возьмёт на себя всю "низкоуровневую" работу по получению сущности из процедуры, её обновлению в БД и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо попробую. Пока плохо знаком с паттернами поэтому не догадался.